# Sum of Column in dataset reportviewer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

i have a table connected to a dataset the table is then filled with items including a column for duration in minutes. For the table i have a group property which it groups on the description of the item. I inserted a row outside the group - below to display the total duration. In the total textbox i use the following expression to calculate the sum of the Duration column:

```
=Sum(Fields!Duration.Value)
```

But for the results i am getting a much larger number than i should and not sure how to resolve the issue or what might be causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same time which had the minutes column i created another row for the total and underneath the minutes I added the following expression in the box/cell:

```
=Sum(Fields!Minutes.Value)
```

The trick for me was that i put the name of the minutes column from the table (field name).